# get and display records sections wise

Tags: php, mysql

3 tables `quiz_sections`, `quiz_attempts` and `question_attempts` tables having their columns as shown below attached screenshot.

`$USER->id` is the current logged in user id variable.

Here is my code

```
<?php
echo "Current User ID : ".$USER->id."<br />";
$quizsections = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz_sections");
while($quizsectionsrslt = mysql_fetch_array($quizsections)){
    echo $quizsectionsheading = $quizsectionsrslt['heading']."<br />";
    $quizsectionsquizid = $quizsectionsrslt['quizid'];
    $quizsectionsfirstslot = $quizsectionsrslt['firstslot'];
    $quizattempts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz_attempts WHERE `quiz`=$quizsectionsquizid AND `userid`=$USER->id");
    while($quizattemptsrslt = mysql_fetch_array($quizattempts)){
        $quizattemptsids = $quizattemptsrslt['id'];
        $quizattemptsattempt = $quizattemptsrslt['attempt'];
        $quizattemptsquiz = $quizattemptsrslt['quiz'];
        $questionattempts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question_attempts WHERE `questionusageid`=$quizattemptsids");
        while($questionattemptsrslt = mysql_fetch_array($questionattempts)){
            echo $questionattemptsid = $questionattemptsrslt['id'];
        }
    }
}
```

The output i got

[image]

[image]

i want to split the result for `userid=3`

Aptitude

> 1 2 3 4...10

Arithmetic

> 11 12 13 ...20

Reasoning

> 21 22 23 ...30

Computers

> 31 32 33 ...40

And result for `userid=4` from 41 to 80.

These are the tables structure.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: No pictures thanks. Just proper DDLs and a desired result set

Comment: you mean, want to remove table structure screens?

Comment: @Raja Post something that we can copy and paste into sqlfiddle.

Comment: @Barmar, please check it is possible to copy and paste my code.

Comment: Stop using those deprecated `mysql_*` functions please. Use PDO / MySQLi instead.

Comment: @Raptor, Thanks. But, i don't now how to use them.

Comment: Please, could anybody help me with this to get the result which is i have requirement.

Comment: @Raja please read the documentation. `mysql_*` functions have security issues and not advise to use.

Comment: Okay. Help me with this for now. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you just need to add `<br>` before the section  heading, and put spaces between the IDs.

Comment: @Barmar, It is giving all the records to all the sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$quizsectionsfirstslot` in thr `question_attempts` query:

```
$questionattempts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question_attempts 
                                WHERE `questionusageid`=$quizattemptsids 
                                AND slot BETWEEN $quizsectionsfirstslot AND $quizsectionsfirstslot + 9");
```

Comment: it is working awesome. But, How about if `Aptitude` have 15, `Arithmetic` have 10, `Reasoning` have 5 and `Computers` have 15.??

Counts

Comment: You should change `quiz_sections` so it also has a `lastslot` column.

Comment: Or instead of having `firstslot` and `lastslot`, add a `sectionid` column to `question_attempts`.

Comment: We don't have `lastslot` column, having limits in `firstslot` column only, see `quiz_sections` table.

Comment: I know you don't. I'm telling you that you SHOULD have that so you know what the end of the range is.

Comment: Yeah. Fine, i will try to get the end of the range. If not, i will ask you here.  :) :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82568/discussion-between-raja-and-barmar).